# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Don't understand why I get this error : 
==> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tourist',
  templateUrl: 'tourist.html',
})
export class TouristPage {

    tourist : Array<any> ;
    key: any;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
    ) {
        this.tourist = navParams.get("tourist");
        this.key = this.tourist.key;
    }
```

Comment: `tourist` is an array

Comment: Typical arrays don't have a `.key` property.

Comment: Key is a value, not the key of the array, I can have the same problem with "name" value in the "tourist" array. How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

`any[]` means "An array containing any kind of value".

Arrays have a [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) property (although it is a function, so probably not what you are looking for) but no `key` property.

Possibly you want to get the values from the array and look at their `key` properties.

Consider [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this purpose.

Comment: You mean, I should foreach the "tourist" array first ?

Comment: @Matthieu — I mean you probably want `tourist[0].key` and `tourist[1].key` and `tourist[2].key` and etc … but its speculation at this point.

Comment: my array "tourist" when I console.log it looks like : {available: true, gp: 58, lat: 4..., key : 12345} I have only 1 row...

Comment: @Matthieu — Then possibly you have declared the wrong type when you said `tourist : Array<any>`

Answer (score 1):

You've declared "tourist" as an Array, you said in comments that when you do console.log it returns `{available: true, gp: 58, lat: 4..., key : 12345}` , knowing that I presume tourist is an object of type any.

Maybe if you change `tourist : Array<any> ;` to `tourist : any ;` it will work.